How to use input values for computation in an Observable doc?
Suppose I set up an Observable doc called number.md that looks as follows:
```js

const x = view(Inputs.range());
console.log("x", x);

const x2 = 2 * x;
```

<p>
Here is x: ${x}.
Here is x2: ${x2}
</p>

If I visit http://localhost:3000/number I get x, but not x2:

How do I compute x2 from the value of x given from the current value of the input, and display x2 properly?
I'm using @observablehq 1.5.1.

Answer from the forum:

Observable’s reactive updates only work between blocks. When one of the outputs of a block changes, any dependent blocks will re-run. Since x2 is defined in the same block as x, it isn’t re-computed when x changes.


Instead, you should use something like

```js
const x = view(Inputs.range());
```

```js
const x2 = 2 * x;
```

Here is x: ${x}. Here is x2: ${x2}


Because x2 is in a separate block than x, it will receive reactive updates.

